# WF4 persistence is slow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I currently have a WCF workflow service with 5000 instances idling waiting for human input. When the service receives a request that updates the database, the persistence takes 5 seconds before persisting to the database.  If I only have 500 instances, the persisting is instant as per the timeToPersist=0 seconds.  Is there anyway to speed this up?

```
'<sqlWorkflowInstanceStore
    connectionStringName="Request"
    instanceCompletionAction="DeleteAll"
    instanceLockedExceptionAction="BasicRetry"
    instanceEncodingOption="GZip"
    hostLockRenewalPeriod="00:00:05"
    runnableInstancesDetectionPeriod="00:00:02"
/>
<workflowIdle
   timeToUnload="00:00:00"
   timeToPersist="00:00:00" />
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentInstances="15"/>'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are deleting the instance of the workflow after the workflow has completed, then this could possibly be one reason for the time required.

This is done in a workflow service using the attribute

```
<sqlWorkflowInstanceStore connectionStringName="SQLInstancing"
                          instanceCompletionAction="DeleteAll"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is note easy to speed this up 
There is latency to retrieve data from the database and to deserialize the information. Try to keep your objects as small as possible 
you can also try to create your own peristence provider - which for example keeps data in memory rather than in the database. You could use a caching engine such as nCache for this. 
 But it's difficult to create a persistence provider.